# What is the Bash equivalent of the set command in C shell?

Tags: bash, unix, tcsh

I need to run this script in the Bash shell as that is the only shell to which I have access on a high performance computing cluster at my present organization.

[image]

Comment: Please replace image with its text. See: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You can't simply run this script under `bash`. You'll need to *port* the entire thing, not just changing how the variables are assigned, to `bash` first.

Comment: It's good that you're changing from C-shell to a bourne-derived shell for your script ([google csh why not](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not)) but that script should be written in a shell at all, it'd be far more efficient and portable (and probably robust) if you write it in awk instead. The guys who invented shell also invented awk for shell to call to manipulate text as your script is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the Bash equivalent of the set command in C shell?

The equivalent is just assigning the variable. There is no special command for that.

```
# set var = 'stuff'
var='stuff'
```

Comment: Will I have to switch the first line from #! bin/csh -f to #! bin/bash as well?

Comment: If you aren't running `bash` explicitly with something like `bash my_script`, yes. But there is a *lot* of things you need to do to make this script work under `bash`, as `csh` uses very different syntax and has different semantics. (That is, `bash` and `csh` are about as similar as Python and Ruby: they look similar, but are not interchangeable.)

Comment: Could you tell me what these things are?